# thanks message instead of contact form

Tags: php, contact-form, sendmessage

I made a contact form and I want when the user sent a mail, a "Your message has been sent" message appear instead of the contact form, staying on the same page how can I fix it ?

**Here is my code**

```
<form method="post" action="" name="contact">
    <div class="column">
        <input name="name" id="name" placeholder="name" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="column-2">
        <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="mail" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="column-3">      
        <textarea id="message" placeholder="Your message" name="message" title="votre message" ></textarea>
    </div> 
    <div class="button">
        <span><input class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="ENVOYER"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['name'])&&!empty($_POST['email'])&&!empty($_POST['message']))// check if everything has been filled out before doing anything else
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: test Contact';
    $to = 'test@test.com';
    $subject = 'Hello';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        if ($name != '' && $email != '') {

                if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
                    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>
                    <span id="success">OK</span>';
                } else {
                    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
                }
            } 
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AJAX. Then from your AJAX call your php code (you need to place your php in a separate folder)

Answer (score 0):

You've got three options.

- Use the bootstrap MODAL component to display the message.
- Call the PHP function through AJAX.
- Create two different pages(One with the
  contact form and another with the PHP code).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to acheive it then you have to redirect the page on success or failure to another page. I have change your code structure a bit as well because you need to check first if the form is submitted.

Here is the working example.

**index.php page**

```
<?php    
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['message'])) {// check if everything has been filled out before doing anything else
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $from = 'From: test Contact';
        $to = 'test@test.com';
        $subject = 'Hello';
        $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

        if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
            if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {

                header("Location: result.php?success=1"); 

            } else {
                 header("Location: result.php?success=0"); 
            }
        } else {
            echo "Name and Email not found";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please fill up all fields";
    }
}
?>


<form method="post" action="" name="contact">
    <div class="column">
        <input name="name" id="name" placeholder="name" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="column-2">
        <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="mail" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="column-3">      
        <textarea id="message" placeholder="Your message" name="message" title="votre message" ></textarea>
    </div> 
    <div class="button">
        <span><input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" name="submit"  value="ENVOYER"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

**result.php page**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['success']) && $_GET['success'] == 1) {
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p><span id="success">OK</span>';
} else {
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
}
?>
```